# Vue.js GET request to API gets blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http, axios, cors

I am trying to fetch data from an API in Vue.js and console.log the response but I get a CORS problem, most specifically:
`from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I read that I need to create a `vue.config.js` file, I did but nothing changed, I also tried just using the fetch api, maybe I am making http calls the wrong way in Vue, how can I get my data and resolve this error?

Here is my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  methods: {},
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://base-url"
      )
      .then(response => console.log(response));
  }
};
</script>
```

and my `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: 'base-url',
    }
}
```

Comment: That error is usually not indicative of what's happening. But my guess is that your backend doesn't allow CORS.

Comment: so its nothing to do with your client. your api has to change

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to set up a middleware in the endpoint you are calling such as following:

```
// ACCEPTING CROSS SITE REQUESTS
api.use(cors());
api.use((req, res, next)=>{
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Please try to add this to your endpoint API you are calling from so that new calls can be authorized.

Answer (score 1):

Your should have 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '
Header

so make sure that your [api base url] returns this header to make your browser
allow your request to go through without being (as way of protection)

More information about [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

An Example in PHP:

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *') // to allow all sites
  ... the rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the header configuration setup for cors in your vue.config?  Should look something like this.

[image]

Comment: I don't sadly its an open API by a company and I don't have access to their backend ;/

Comment: Is it failing to leave your Vue.js app or are you getting blocked by the API?

The headers you send aren't controlled by the API. This segment of code should go along with your devServer settings in your config file.

Comment: These are response headers, which do not belong in the frontend request. The server decides which origins are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In the recent versions of vuejs, for example if the remote api is at http://localhost:9002/tasks then use server config.

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/tasks': 'http://localhost:9002'
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I found out what I was doing wrong, after setting up the proxy I had to change my get request to

```
mounted() {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://localhost:8080/https://base-url"
      )
      .then(response => console.log(response));
```

That fixed the issue.